# How to change header and footer with minutes library

Tags: header-footer, numbering, fancyhdr

I'm using the minutes package (https://ctan.org/pkg/minutes) to write my minutes but I wasn't able to change the header and the footer of my pages. My header should have a custom text in the center. My footer should have a custom text on the left and the page numbering on the right (Page 1 of 2). I tried the fancyhdr and followed different tutorials but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the preamble between `\usepackage{minutes}` and `\begin{document}`.

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{HEADER}
\fancyfoot[L]{LEFT FOOTER}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page {\thepage} of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I put this in my preamble but header and footer did not change

Comment: That is strange. I tried it in the sample document from the `minutes` package and it worked. I did put it after the `\usepackage{minutes}` but that shouldn’t be critical. Without more details about your document it is difficult to say. Did you check the log file for strange warnings or so?

Comment: You said “did not change”, so that seems to imply something else also made headers and footers. Could there be a conflict?

Comment: Seems like you have to put header & footer  after the `\usepackage{minutes}`

Comment: I have added that to the answer. I looked into the minutes.sty and saw that it does a `\pagestyle{headings}`.